# remove a line beginning with text from a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file where I want to remove any entries starting with GATEWAY using python.
The code I have come up with is below (This is based on my limited knowledge of Python as I have only just started learning so please be gentle with me) and searching on SO for this questions previously.

```
import fileinput
phrase = 'GATEWAY'

with open("/tmp/ifcfg-eth0", "rw") as eth0file:
    for line in fileinput.input(eth0file, inplace=True):
        if phrase in line:
            continue
        print line
```

This seems to make sense to me but when I run it I get:

```
 File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input(eth0file, inplace=True):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/fileinput.py", line 322, in readline
    os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on what Im doing wrong greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fileinput.input` expects a filename, not a file.

Comment: @PeterWood is correct if i change to a filename it works :)

Comment: your loop can just be `for line in eth0file:`

Comment: Wrong tool: Use `grep -v PATTERN` to do that.